# how to get list of retweeters using streaming api

Tags: twitter

Is there a way to get the list of retweeters ids using streaming api

REST api has "GET statuses/:id/retweeted_by/ids" for getting the list of retweeters

Streaming api has a "statuses/retweet", but is not a generally available resources.

So the idea is to use "statuses/filter" and filter based on tweet ids.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the results returned by the streaming API, retweeters (if any) are listed here:

```
$retweeters = $tweet->{'retweeted_status'}->{'activities'}->{'retweeters'};
```

Here's a page which shows the ids of retweeters for a stream filtered with a search for the word 'love' — make sure to use your Twitter username and password. Note that the APIs only return the first 100 retweeters.

```
<html><body>
<?php
    echo(str_pad("START<br>",2048));
    @ob_flush();
    flush();

    $opts = array(
        'http'=>array(
            'method'    =>  "POST",
            'content'   =>  'track=love',
            'header' => "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n"
        )
    );

    $context = stream_context_create($opts);
    $username = 'your_twitter_username';
    $password = 'your_twitter_password';
    while (1){
        $instream = fopen('http://'.$username.':'.$password.'@stream.twitter.com/1/statuses/filter.json','r' ,false, $context);
        while(! feof($instream)) {
            if(! ($line = stream_get_line($instream, 20000, "\n"))) {
                continue;
            }else{
                $tweet = json_decode($line);
                $retweeters = array();
                $retweeters = $tweet->{'retweeted_status'}->{'activities'}->{'retweeters'};

                //We store the new post in the database, to be able to read it later
                if (sizeof($retweeters) > 0) {
                    echo("<br><br>");
                    print_r($retweeters);
                }
                @ob_flush();
                flush();
            }
        }
    }
?>
</html></body>
```